# Uninstalled Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows-7, uninstall

So I uninstalled Ubuntu by creating another disc and running Ubuntu on that disc and following the steps to install OS uninstaller and remove it. That didn't take long, but now when I start my computer I get bootmgr error and I don't know how to fix it. I searched for solution online but I don't have any of the Windows discs and I can't get onto windows to create one.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate cause I have uninstalled it but now my computer won't boot windows. I don't think that is the same.

Comment: The advice from the link above explains how to start your live-cd and run boot-repair.

Comment: Did you try running this command (from live CD)? "sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr" It disables GRUB and restores the Windows MBR.

Comment: In case it says lilo package unavailable, install it using apt-get.

Comment: @MadMike The problem isn't Ubuntu, is the good old Windows that borked. It's off-topic since the method he needs is to repair Windows MBR.

Comment: @Brad you need to repair you Windows MBR. There are tons of ways to get the DVD from MS and put it on a DVD/USB (as says the Emerson's answer) I would recommend you to remove the disk where Ubuntu is installed to prevent Windows from removing the GRUB. Once this is done, just boot into Ubuntu, fire up a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Windows disk and open recovery mode and fix the mbr using BootRec.exe
Check this link for more detailed info..
Run the /FixMBR and /FixBoot options.:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

You need the disc to repair the MBR, but if you don't have a disk, another way around is to install Ubuntu again on its partition, it will install GRUB, then boot into Windows, use EasyBCD to fix the MBR and other problems, then delete the Ubuntu partition using Partition Manager.

If you don't want to use EasyBCD, you can make a recovery disk or USB drive from within Windows.

Links:

EasyBCD:  http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

Comment: I don't have the installation disc I don't have any discs I would need to create on some how but how.

Comment: See my edited answer